# JVM configuration on 64-bit Linux

Tags: memory, configuration, jvm, 64-bit

I have a server application that runs on 64-bit Ubuntu server with 4Gb RAM.
When I set JVM (We use Sun JVM 1.6) configuration parameters like this: -Xms1024m -Xmx2560m, I see a strange memory allocation when starting the application (It runs on Tomcat 6).
Ubuntu's "top" command shows that the virtual memory size is almost 3,2Gb. I don't understand whether Ubuntu allocated the memory I asked for when starting the JVM, or maybe Ubuntu adds a part swap to the -Xmx value and thus I get this big size. 
If I run on 32-bit Ubuntu server and configure -Xmx1536m I see 1721m when running "top" command. Can anybody explain me what are those deltas and when they come from?
I have other processes running on those instances and I want to understand what memory configuration I should apply for them taking into account the results of Ubuntu's "top" command.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out a Profiler like Yourkit?

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will use a certain amount of extra memory for internal housekeeping purposes - this [link](http://mfinocchiaro.files.wordpress.com/2008/07/java-virtual-machine-neutral.pdf) may help:

*Note also that the Permanent Generation is tacked onto the end of the Old Generation. There is also a
small code cache of 50Mb for internal JVM memory management. This means that the total initial heap
size = ‐Xms + ‐XX:PermSize + ~50Mb and that the maximum total heap size = ‐Xmx + ‐XX:+MaxPermSize
+ ~50Mb. For example, if –Xms/–Xmx are set to 512m and –XX:PermSize/MaxPermSize are set to 128m,
the total VM will actually about 700 Mb in size.*